# SPL autoload and extending abstract classes

Tags: php, abstract-class, spl-autoload-register

I keep an abstract class definition in a directory called /classes. It looks like this:

```
abstract class baseController {

    protected $registry;

    //Obtain registry object
    protected function __construct($reg) {
        $this->registry = $reg;
    }

    protected function show() {

    }

}
```

In the /controllers/ directory (they share the same parent folder) I have my specific controller class files. For instance,

```
class indexController extends baseController {

    public function show() {

        //render index page
        $this->registry->view->render('index');

    }
```

}

I use two `spl_autoload_register()` calls in my config script to make sure that both directories are found when classes are needed - but when I try to instantiate indexController from my router.class.php file (which is in the /classes/ directory) I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to protected baseController::__construct() from context 'router'...
```

It's identifying the line: `$this->controller = new indexController($this->registry);` as the culprit.

The __construct is protected, but indexController should be inheriting from baseController and therefore, since the __construct method isn't redefined, it **should** be calling the parent classes constructor. Or so I thought.

What the heck is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use public definition in `__construct` method, since you instantiate the class outside the class context (ex in Router class).

This may work if you instantiate it inside another class that extends `baseController`.

Comment: So, if I'm instantiating a class that extends a base class in the context of a third (unrelated) class, then I need to define the constructor method as public? I don't understand why that would be an issue, since the object I'm creating is still an extended version of the abstract class.

Comment: This worked, but I would love an explanation about why the child class was "out of context" in this case?

Comment: Imagine that when you call `new indexController()` it is like a shortcut of calling `__construct()` method for this class. So like other methods in classes it must be public if you call it outside of class context.

Comment: OH - I think I just got it. Even if indexController didn't `extend` another class, I couldn't instantiate it in a normal block of code because the `__construct()` method is protected, not public! Am I right?

Comment: Yes that 's right. If the `__construct` method is not public you cannot instatiate the class outside the class context.